# Reloading Fragment with the new value

Tags: java, android, arraylist

When I am trying to reload again Fragment the constructor value is not getting changed. For example if I am opening the application it's working perfectly, But when I change anything with the Arraylist and try to reload the fragment, Somehow my ArrayList is returning 0 though I am passing the list.

My activity code is:

```
private void setGraphComponent(ArrayList<SpinnerAdapter> weatherSensor, ArrayList<SpinnerAdapter> cattleSensor, ArrayList<SpinnerAdapter> weatherSensor2, ArrayList<SpinnerAdapter> volt, ArrayList<SpinnerAdapter> sign, ArrayList<SpinnerAdapter> vehicleSensor) {
        ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        ViewPager graphPager = findViewById(R.id.graphPager);

        if (weatherSensor.size() > 1) {
            viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new GraphFragment(this, StaticConfig.SENSOR_1, weatherSensor, 1));
        }
}
```

And my fragment code is:

```
public GraphFragment(Context context, String title, ArrayList<SpinnerAdapter> adapters, int sensorType) {
        this.context = context;
        this.title = title;
        this.spinnerAdapters = adapters;
        this.sensorType = sensorType;
    }

 public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.graph_fragement, container, false);

        TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        Spinner devices = view.findViewById(R.id.devices);


        init_volleyCallback();
        stringVolleyService = new StringVolleyService( stringResult, context);
// Here in spinnerAdapters when I am loading first time its coming 3 count which suppose to be but when I reload it again its coming 0. 
        setSpinner(spinnerAdapters, devices);

        textView.setText(title);
        return view;
    }
```

Any suggestions will be of great help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should not create a custom constructor when using fragments in Android. You can

1. pass arguments to a fragment through `setArguments(Bundle)` and
   later retrieve them with `getArguments()`
2. you may use `onAttach(Context)`.

These are specified in the
[documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#Fragment()).

In your case maybe overriding `onAttach(Context)` makes sense since you get a context instance and you are guaranteed that this this *is the first place application code can run where the fragment is ready to be used*.

So implementing `onAttach` in your fragment could look like that,

```
@Override
public void onAttach (Context context){
 YourActivity activity = (YourActivity) context;
 this.title = activity.title; // or activity.getTitle(), you get the idea
 this.spinnerAdapters = activity.adapters;
 this.sensorType = activity.sensorType;
}
```